# what is the correct way to wait for all the volumes to get attached to instances

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, fog

I am using fog library to create instances in AWS, while creating the instances I am also attaching EBS volumes to the instances like this:

```
server = conn.servers.new(:image_id => 'ami-XXXXX',
                          :flavor_id => 'm1.medium',
                          :keyname => 'secret123',
                          :groups => 'gourp123',
                          :block_device_mapping => [
                            { 
                              "DeviceName"=>"sdi", 
                              "Ebs.VolumeSize"=>10, 
                              "Ebs.DeleteOnTermination"=>false
                            },
                            {
                              "DeviceName"=>"sdj", 
                              "Ebs.VolumeSize"=>10, 
                              "Ebs.DeleteOnTermination"=>false
                            }
                          ])
```

Now, I have to format the volumes that are being attached using `net-ssh`, I noticed that using `server.wait_for { ready? }` does not help as it waits until the server gets into running state and returns back. Which is not a reliable method to format the partitions as the volumes might not have been mounted yet!

So I found another option which is to wait for the console output of the instance to get back using: 
`server.wait_for { console_output.body['output'] =~ /^cloud-init boot finished/ }` 
and then format the volumes, which is getting the job done for now. But the console_output takes a very long time to come back.

Is there any better/reliable way of making sure the volumes are mounted and ready for partitioning?